# I have two monitors on my computer, how can I set a different wallpaper to each

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors, desktop-background

I have two monitors on my computer, how can I set a different wallpaper to each. I don't use workspaces, two screens are enough. I know it's possible to set a different wallpaper to each workspace but I can't find anything on individual screens. It is a laptop, but I have two graphic cards running SLI mode so both monitors are running off of the first.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem since years. Manually create a big image with GIMP - that's the only solution for now.

Comment: It is real easy, in fact send me a copy of both images and i will do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Install and use a program called `nitrogen`.  Its in the repos, has a nice GUI, and will allow you to do what you want.